# SAP B1 how to load sap form to VisualStudio IDE to modify it?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sapb1

I've Installed SAP B1DEStup, because I want to hide **total** field in PO screen from some users, but I don't know how to load the form to MS Visual Studio to modify it, please guide me?

Answer (score 0):

Loading the form into visual studio isn't something that I know how to do, nor do I know if it is even possible.
However, hiding a field on the PO screen shouldn't be too tricky.
I'm assuming you have some knowledge of the SDK/DI/UI so I'll save myself the time of digging out all the syntax (i'll leave that bit for you).

First, turn on system information, either go to view --> System information, or press
 Ctrl + Shift + I

Each form has a number of items. Everything, and I mean EVERYTHING you see on a form is an item of some sort, with an identifier (ID number)

To find the identifiers for this simply hover over the field you wish to hide:

[image: Hover and look]

Then check the bar at the bottom where I wrote "look here" and it will be something like this:
[Form = 142 Item = 29 Pane = 0 Variable = 91]

In this instance your code would be interested in the form number, and the item number.
In my example, a Purchase Order form is number 142, and the field I hovered over (Total Payment Due) is item number 29.

Hope this helps!